# Reverse Proxy Requests from the loaded website are not being proxied

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have  a reverse proxy set up like this.

http://example.com/3rdpartywebsite/ -> http://internal.addr/3rdpartywebsite/

So the requests to example.com are reverse proxied to a website on the internal network.

The problem is that the 3rdpartywebsite is jquery and it is running requests back to the host once it is loaded in the browser.  These requests (from the loaded app) are not being redirected to http://example.com/3rdpartyProxy/ they are instead going to http://example.com/

This seems to have something to do with what the standard getHttpObject() returns. It doesn't know about the "3rdpartyProxy" part of the url and simply returns http://example.com/

Here are the contents of my reverse proxy config from apache:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /3rdpartywebsite/ http://internal.addr/
ProxyPassReverse /3rdpartywebsite/ http://internal.addr/
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not even really sure where to start looking here.  Is the problem with the reverse proxy, or should I be looking at the website itself for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question! Yay.

The way I got this working in the end is to use the following site config.  I use a reverse proxy followed by a rewrite.  In my case the rewrite was simple enough to be handled with one rewrite of cgi-bin calls to the 3rd party service.

The right way for the 3rd party service to work would be with relative paths, but because absolute paths were used I was forced into this solution.

It is important to note that this WILL NOT WORK if the rewrite engine takes effect BEFORE the reverse proxy.  You will end up with a dead link.

Virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@host.net<br>
    ServerName      host.net
    ServerAlias     www.host.net
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/
    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /3rdPartyWebsite/ http://192.168.0.1/
    ProxyPassReverse /3rdPartyWebsite/ http://192.168.0.1/


    #RewriteLog /home/rfmondial/rewrite.log
    #RewriteLogLevel 9

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory />
            AllowOverride none
            order deny,allow
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            allow from all

            RewriteEngine On
            #http://host/ --> http://domain/3rdPartyWebsite/ (default ROOT in Tomcat) a
            RewriteCond !%{REQUEST_URI} !nt-gui/
            RewriteRule ^(cgi-bin.*)$ 3rdPartyWebsite/$1 [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```